# Loss function for sparse tagging

Tags: rnn

I am writing a musical transcription system with a RNN (LSTM).

- Input: 1 vector of features per timestep (about 40 timesteps in a second)
- Output: 1 binary vector of notes per timestep (dimension=36) (1 is on, 0 if off).
- Model : LSTM(512) + LSTM(256) + Dense(36, activation='sigmoid')

I am currently training on monophonic data (i.e. my output has at most one 1 per timestep).

The problem is that because of the sparsity the best strategy to use is to always return 0.
I tried the loss functions 'mean_squared_error', 'mean_absolute_error', 'binary_crossentropy', 'cosine_proximity' and one custom I wrote with keras :

```
K.sum(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) * K.mean(y_pred, axis=-1) / K.maximum(K.mean(y_pred * y_true, axis=-1), K.epsilon())
```

All those function led with sufficient training to the always zero output.

I can either change my loss function or my encoding, but the problem is that I need to support polyphonic data, i.e. when there is more than one class to select.

Or can I train as many LSTM as there are notes (88 for a piano keyboard), and each one detects if its note is played but I think this is pretty much equivalent, isn't it ?

I think my data is pretty much equivalent to what keras calls categorical data (binary matrix).

Currently I have only 36 classes, and 24 are always zero.

Comment: Have you tried `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of 1 note at a time maximum you could use categorical_crossentropy as loss and add a class for when no note is played. This is a log loss on a last softmax layer. This would turn it into a 37 one-hot-encoding representation.

In the case of having the possibility of multiple notes I would keep the 36 (or 88 for the pian) dimensional representation and have a sigmoid activation on each of the notes at the end. Then sum the binary log loss of each of the nodes and use that as the loss. Then you can treshold the nodes individually at prediction time to see if a note is on or off.

Comment: Good point for the 1 note case, I though about it.

Comment: For the multiple notes case, I already take the mean and not the sum (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/objectives.py#L48), and thresholding is what binary_accuracy does in keras (although I did not change the default threshold=.5).